# пунктуация: тире или запятая в придаточном

Tags: пунктуация

*Сегодня, кроме психологии, можно указать еще лишь одно научное направление, в рамках которого исследователи стремятся решать эту же предельно сложную задачу(,-) создание систем искусственного интеллекта (СИИ).* После "задачу" нужно поставить тире или запятую, или ничего не нужно?

Answer (score 1):

user176815, вы знаете, с этой темой "тире или запятая" вы влезли в один из самых запутанных вопросов русской пунктуации. Во всяком случае я его к таковым отношу. Достаточно сказать, что правила различают случаи, когда стоят два знака подряд и те же самые знаки, которые считаются единым знаком. Подробнее я вам найду ссылку, если нужно.

А пока давайте разберемся с грамматикой. Какое основание тут для запятой? Только закрыть придаточное. А где придаточное кончается? Вот вопрос, который без автора и не решить. Если "создание систем ИИ" это *направление*, то конец придаточного - после задача, "запятая" нужна. Если же "создание" - это "задача", то всё вместе "в рамках которого исследователи стремятся решать эту же предельно сложную задачу(:) создание систем искусственного интеллекта  (СИИ)" - или одно большое и длинное придаточное, или, вернее всего, - два с бессоюзной связью.

А какие основания для тире? Только интонационные (резкая смена событий), но это здесь вряд ли. Тут скорее будет двоеточие, ибо смысл присоединения "а именно". Правила здесь.
http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185
Беда в том, что грамматика тут не очевидна, можно ли считать всю конструкцию бессоюзным сложным - большой вопрос.

При этом, однако, двоеточие в отличие от тире, обладает одним замечательным свойством. Оно "поглощает"запятую, даже мотивированную иными, нежели само двоеточие, причинами. Другими словами, поставив двоеточие, можно уже не думать ни о запятой, ни о тире, а вот запятая и тире друг друга совсем не исключают.

Если вы ничего не поняли (скорее всего!), то по-простому. Я веду к тому, чтобы поставить двоеточие.

> *Сегодня, кроме психологии, можно указать еще лишь одно научное направление, в рамках которого исследователи стремятся решать эту же предельно сложную задачу: создание систем искусственного интеллекта (СИИ).*

Не уверен, что это по правилам, но разобраться до конца тут все равно никто не сможет (по причинам, изложенным выше), а значит, такой вариант пунктуации имеет некоторые основания для существования. А смотрится он много лучше остальных.
(+)
Выяснилось, что это как раз не по правилам. Я неверно истолковал грамматику. Это не бессоюзное сложное (и не может им быть), это приложение.

*Интересно было бы услышать людей, реально владеющих вопросом на уровне проверки ЕГЭ хотя бы. Что там современная наука говорит по поводу подобных заморочек. Я с удовольствием сниму все свои идеи, если мне растолкуют, в чем я неправ.)))*
(+)
Услышал. Объяснили.

Два варианта - в зависимости от смысла.

*Сегодня, кроме психологии, можно указать еще лишь одно научное направление, в рамках которого исследователи стремятся решать эту же предельно сложную задачу - создание систем искусственного интеллекта (СИИ)*
- если СИИ - это (по мысли автора) **задача**.

*Сегодня, кроме психологии, можно указать еще лишь одно научное направление, в рамках которого исследователи стремятся решать эту же предельно сложную задачу, - создание систем искусственного интеллекта (СИИ).*
- если СИИ - это **направление**.

(+) Я, кстати, не совсем уверен в необходимости обособления оборота с "кроме ...", от смысла зависит. Но, вроде бы, тут скорее т.н. "включающее *кроме*", так что запятые скорее всего нужны. 
С этим сюда - 
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_370

Comment: спасибо, мне понравились ваши рассуждения. Поставлю двоеточие

Comment: @user176815, отставить двоеточие! Простите, обманул Вас по своей серости. При приложениях двоеточие невозможно, в этом из отличие от бессоюзных сложных. Остается тире, возможно в сочетании с заяпятой, это уже по смыслу.  Придется все-таки уточнять у автора. Ответ дополняю.

Comment: Ого! ничего себе! как быстро ситуация меняется. А ведь двоеточие очень органично бы уточняло и расшифровывало бы смысл... Что ж! Буду осмыслять новую информацию! Спасибо!)

Comment: Ну уж простите. Не мог я Вас дальше обманывать. Меня не просто поправили, меня переубедили. Ситуация не поменялась, поменялось наше знание о ней.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не спутать название направления с содержанием задачи, лучше повторить слово "направление":

... эту же предельно сложную задачу: направление создания систем искусственного интеллекта (СИИ).

... эту же предельно сложную задачу. Это направление создания систем искусственного интеллекта (СИИ).

Comment: Спасибо! я бы тоже заменила)) но автору текста хочется, чтобы я только исправила орфографию, ничего не меняя. А я не особо сильна))

Answer (score 0):

Предлагается вариант:

Сегодня, кроме психологии, можно указать еще лишь одно научное направление, в рамках которого исследователи стремятся решать **эту же** предельно сложную задачу - создание систем искусственного интеллекта (СИИ).

Обособленное приложение входит в состав придаточного предложения и является пояснительным к слову "задача", на это однозначно указывает местоимение "это" (эту задачу, а именно какую).